# Prettier is Indenting by 2 spaces instead of 4 on "Shift + Alt + F"

Tags: visual-studio-code, vuejs3, prettier

I am using Vue 3 and VS Code with Prettier as my code formatter, and I want the indentation to be 4 spaces instead of 2, and I've configured 4 spaces on the bottom right side of my VS Code. But still whenever I format my code it indents everything to 2 spaces. I've tried reinstalling Prettier and VS Code, but it's still the same!

Comment: Try go to VS Code settings via "Ctrl + ," and search for "Prettier: Tab Width". Change that value from 2 to 4 and see if it works

Comment: Is it possible that the formatter settings have changed but the file hasn't been forcibly reformatted? Try using `Shift` + `Alt` + `F` to reformat the file using the formatter's settings.

Comment: @AnsonH Thanks, it worked, one more thing how to do I keep "tab" as my default indentation in VS Code? Whenever I make a new file, it changes by to spaces.

Comment: You can add a `.editorconfig` to your root which tells VS Code what to use. The settings you are looking for are: `indent_size = 4` and `indent_style = tab`